# Does binding in question 1 implies binding in question 2

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

Consider optimization problem
$$
\max_x f(x)
$$
$x$ could be of any dimension.

Question 1: There is only one constraint $g(x)\ge 0$.

Question 2: There are two constraints $g(x)\ge 0, h(x)\ge 0$.

Suppose I can show that $h(x)\ge 0$ is always binding in question 2. Is there any relationship between the binding-slackness of $g(x)\ge 0$ in question 1 and 2?

For instance, can we show that $g(x)=0$ in question 1 implies $g(x)=0$ in question 2, or vice versa?

If not, what additional assumptions do I need to make it happen?

Thanks a lot!